# Hive performance

Tags: hadoop, hive

I work on hive and i am new to it. I am facing some issues regarding the performance in hive query.

1. Number of mappers allocated to my job is very low even though there
   are hundreds of mappers available. I have tried setting
   `mapred.map.tasks=200`. But it takes only 20 to 30 mappers. I
   understand, number of mappers depend upon the inputsplit. Is there
   any other option to increase the mappers? if no then why is the
   parameter(`mapred.map.tasks`) introduced ?
2. Is there any resource where i can understand to correlate hive
   queries to map-reduce jobs, i.e where the different part of the
   query is executed?

Comment: how is your input data organized? There are some situations where Hive cannot split the input freely into a(n idealized) number of mappers. For instance if you are loading .gz files, I believe the standard behavior is 1 .gz file -> 1 map, regardless the number of nodes available.

Comment: i am querying against a hive table. But the table is very large approx 10 TB size..

Comment: The size of table does not matter , what @MikeRepass was referring to is the layout of the data files. Is your table a single compressed file or is it made of several files. Some compression and file format support compression.

Answer (score 2):

For more information about setting map tasks, check this link: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces. Basically, mapred.map.tasks is just a hint; it doesn't really control anything usually.

To see how Hive queries are executed, simply preface your query with `explain`. For example: `explain select foo from bar;`. If you need even more information, there's also `explain extended`.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question has been asked long time ago, I'll try to answer it even though some of the suggestions here would not be available at the time when question has been asked.

To optimize Hive performance:

- Tuning the number of mappers and reducers used by your Hive request; this could be done by tuning the input size for each mapper `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`, and the input size for each reducer: `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer`

bare in mind that "the more the better"  is not always true. So you need to tune those numbers to your needs.

- Optimize the joins, convert Joins to map-joins, if one of the table is small table (if possible)... 
  (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization)
- Partition your table on columns that are often used in conditions (WHERE).
  For example if you are requesting frequently
   `SELECT * from myTable WHERE someColumn = 'someValue'`
   it is recommended to partition your table on the column 'someColumn' 
  This will let your query search just the partition files  someColumn=SomePartition instead of searching the whole table files.
- Compressing the intermediate results may enhance the performance in some cases (depending on your hardware configuration, network and CPU / memory). This could be done by setting the property: `hive.intermediate.compression.codec`
- Choosing the right compression codec, for example using Snappy ([as in here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-3-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_23_5.html)):

  ```
  SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
  SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
  SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
  ```

**Not been available at the time of question:**

- Using optimized file format to store your table , instead of using Text File, or Sequence File, you could use ORC (hive 0.11 +) for example (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC )
- Using another engine to execute your queries on, instead of MapReduce, you could use Tez or even Spark.To use [tez for example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Tez):

  ```
  <property>
      <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
      <value>tez</value>
  </property>
  ```

For further optimization you could refer [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/5-ways-make-hive-queries-run-faster/)

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease 'mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize'  to increase the number of mappers (more splits).